# Universal links in iOS with query parameters not working

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-universal-links

I have universal links setup in the app and It works fine for 2 url routes but fails in case of a third route in which query params are used.
This is the url I want to work on
`/register?referral=code`
Following is the app site file hosted

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "K85K7YK4HY.com.send.sprint",
                "paths": [ "/login/*", "/change-password/*","/verify-successful/*”,”/register/*”]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried using different paths in the app site association file.
`/register`
`/register/*`

Comment: Your quotes looks broken. Is it a SO formatting issue or really the case?

Comment: @NicolasBraun it must be formatting issue but still not the cause for the issue.